Electrical Field Energy VS Magnetic Field Energy
I read this paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/382792886_Experimental_measurement_for_the_optical_power_of_interference_between_two_coherent_Gaussian_laser_beams
According to this paper, there is difference between the Electrical Field Energy & Magnetic Field Energy in case of 2 Gaussian waves interference. As I know from text books, the pointing vector is ⟨Sz⟩=ϵ0cEx^2. the power is P=∫⟨Sz⟩dA. So, how can I calculate the total power for the 2 EM gaussian wave @ interference point in this case? Do I need to make separate calculation for electrical field power and magnetic field power.
